# How can I perform a DragDrop/swap of a ChartControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, drag-and-drop, devexpress

I'm trying to allow my users to swap two DevExpress chart controls (although I believe pretty much any control should work...), by dragging one over the top of the other.  I have done this for my TabControl (to allow swapping/moving of tabs), but for some reason I appear to be missing something here which is stopping me doing the same with my ChartControl.

It "should" draw a grey-ish box over the chartcontrol and allow the user to drag it to wherever they like, but I just get a black circle with a stripe through it.

Here is the code I have written so far, hopefully one of you will be able to spot the mistake and I can stop pulling my hair out! :)

```
private void ChartControlMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle Mouse move only if left button is pressed.
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        var chartControl = (ChartControl)sender;

        // If the mouse moves outside the rectangle, start the drag.
        if (!rectDragBoxFromMouseDown.Equals(Rectangle.Empty)
            & !rectDragBoxFromMouseDown.Contains(e.X, e.Y))
        {
            Invalidate();
            DoDragDrop(chartControl, DragDropEffects.Move);
            CalcRectDragBox(e.X, e.Y);
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
}

private void ChartControlMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    CalcRectDragBox(e.X, e.Y);
}

private void CalcRectDragBox(int x, int y)
{
    // Remember the point where the mouse down occurred. The DragSize indicates
    // the size that the mouse can move before a drag event should be started.
    var dragSize = SystemInformation.DragSize;
    // Create a rectangle using the DragSize, with the mouse position being
    // at the center of the rectangle.
    rectDragBoxFromMouseDown = new Rectangle(
        new Point(x - (dragSize.Width/2), y - (dragSize.Height/2)), dragSize);
}

private void ChartControlDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var chartControl = (ChartControl)sender;

    // get the control we are hovering over.
    var hitInformation = chartControl.CalcHitInfo(chartControl.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y)));
    if ((hitInformation != null))
    {
        //ChartHitInfo hoverTab = hitInformation;

        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(ChartControl)))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
            var dragTab = (ChartControl)e.Data.GetData(typeof(ChartControl));

            if (dragTab != chartControl)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < layoutControlGroupDashboard.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    var layoutControlItem = layoutControlGroupDashboard.Items[i] as LayoutControlItem;
                    if (layoutControlItem != null && layoutControlItem.Control == chartControl)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < layoutControlGroupDashboard.Items.Count; j++)
                        {
                            var controlItem = layoutControlGroupDashboard.Items[j] as LayoutControlItem;
                            if (controlItem != null && controlItem.Control == dragTab)
                            {
                                if (!_ignoreNextDrag)
                                {
                                    _ignoreNextDrag = true;
                                    layoutControlGroupDashboard.BeginInit();
                                    var layoutControlItemi = layoutControlGroupDashboard.Items[i] as LayoutControlItem;
                                    if (layoutControlItemi != null)
                                    {
                                        Control tempControlI =
                                            layoutControlItemi.Control;
                                        var layoutControlItemj = layoutControlGroupDashboard.Items[j] as LayoutControlItem;
                                        if (layoutControlItemj != null)
                                        {
                                            layoutControlItemi.BeginInit();
                                            layoutControlItemj.BeginInit();
                                            Control tempControlJ =
                                                layoutControlItemj.Control;


                                            layoutControlItemi.Control =
                                                null;
                                            layoutControlItemj.Control =
                                                null;
                                            layoutControlItemi.Control =
                                                tempControlJ;
                                            layoutControlItemj.Control =
                                                    tempControlI;
                                            layoutControlItemi.EndInit();
                                            layoutControlItemj.EndInit();
                                        }
                                    }

                                    layoutControlGroupDashboard.EndInit();
                                    break;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    _ignoreNextDrag = false;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }
}
```

Again, the idea is to allow the user to swap the controls around just click click-dragging things around... Hopefully it's just something simple I'm missing, but I can't see it for the life of me!

Edit:  This is something I tried (adding my chart to a panel first...)

```
            Panel panel = new Panel();
            panel.Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            panel.Controls.Add(chartControl);

            var dashboardItem = new LayoutControlItem(layoutControlDashboard, panel)
                                    {
                                        Padding = new DevExpress.XtraLayout.Utils.Padding(0),
                                        Spacing = new DevExpress.XtraLayout.Utils.Padding(0),
                                        SizeConstraintsType = SizeConstraintsType.Custom
                                    };
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me without any modifications. Did you enabled the AllowDrop option of chart controls?

Comment: @Uranus Do they swap places?  I didn't enable "AllowDrop", but even with it enabled they don't change places.  If they swapped for you what type of control did you have them in?  I have mine in LayoutControlItems in a LayoutControl.

Comment: Yes, they do. I have put controls on different panels to test your code, since it change parent to flip controls. This code will not work if you put chart controls in the LayoutControl, becaues in this situation the LayoutControl is a parent of both. It is necessary to move layout items, instead.

Comment: @Uranus - I updated it so that it works with a LayoutControl, but it doesn't work every time, and after you drag you have to click to make the swap happen... Very strange behavior, any ideas?

Comment: I have added an answer. Please check how that code work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the modified ChartControlDragOver method which work in case the ChartControl is placed in the LayoutControl:

```
private void ChartControlDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
var chartControl = (ChartControl)sender;

// get the control we are hovering over.
var hitInformation = chartControl.CalcHitInfo(chartControl.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y)));
if ((hitInformation != null)) {
    //ChartHitInfo hoverTab = hitInformation;

    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(ChartControl))) {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        var dragTab = (ChartControl)e.Data.GetData(typeof(ChartControl));
        if (dragTab == chartControl) return;
        InsertType insertType = InsertType.Left;
        Point hitPoint = chartControl.Parent.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        if (dragTab.Bounds.Left < hitPoint.X && dragTab.Bounds.Right > hitPoint.X) {
            if (dragTab.Bounds.Top > hitPoint.Y)
                insertType = InsertType.Top;
            else if (dragTab.Bounds.Bottom < hitPoint.Y)
                insertType = InsertType.Bottom;
        } else if (dragTab.Bounds.Right < hitPoint.X)
            insertType = InsertType.Right;
        else if (dragTab.Bounds.Left > hitPoint.X)
            insertType = InsertType.Left;
        LayoutControl layout = (LayoutControl)chartControl.Parent;
        layout.GetItemByControl(dragTab).Move(layout.GetItemByControl(chartControl), insertType);
    }
} else {
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
}
```

}

Comment: That does work spectacularly well for lateral moves.  So if I have two controls with one above another or to the side of the other this works REALLY well! :)  The issue I have is that with the various layouts that my users can have if they drag things around with this code then they can end up in a situation where they get stuck (moving things doesn't do anything).  I've thrown together a very crude sample app for you to check out, go to tab2 and click add a couple of times and then go back to tab1 and drag things around for a minute... I literally want them to swap places.

Comment: I've voted you up and a thank you for trying, but can't give you the answer as it doesn't quite work properly... I originally thought it would be that the chart would have a parent of LayoutControlItem which I could switch over and it would just work! :S

Here is my sample app: http://www9.zippyshare.com/v/18361378/file.html

Comment: If you put chart controls in the panel, and put these panels in the layout control, you can use the code you used with the TabControl.

Comment: Are you saying one panel per chat control?  And is there a specific type of panel you'd suggest I use?  I tried something (in my edit above) but it didn't work...

Comment: Since this does what most other people will need I'll mark you as the answer.  It's close enough that I'm sure I can build on it for my own (crazy) requirements! :)